Generalizing an experiment to pick an element from a set with probability in a given range given perturbed uniform sampling access
This question is an offshoot of my attempts to generalize an interesting observation I made and posted on MSE. For completeness, I will start with the context and then ask my question.
Context
Let $X$ be a finite set, with $|X|=t$. Suppose we want to sample points from $X$ by going over each of them and picking them up with probability $p$ and not picking them up with probability $1-p$. Then what is the probability that a particular point $x_0$ is picked? Clearly it is just $p$.
But this is time consuming to do, so we should try simulating this with a little better expected speed-up. What we do is we sample a number $N$ from $\text{Binomial}(t,p)$. Then we pick up elements from $X$ uniformly and independently till we have $N$ distinct elements (basically sampling without replacement). Now what is the probability of $x_0$ being picked up?
Well, suppose we are picking up $k$ points. Basic probability says that $$\mathbb P(\text{$x_0$ picked}\mid N=k)=\frac{k}{t}$$ and hence by law of total probability, we get \begin{align*}\mathbb P(x_0\text{ picked})&=\sum_{k=0}^t\mathbb P(\text{$x_0$ picked}\mid N=k)\mathbb P(N=k)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{k}{t}\binom{t}{k}p^k(1-p)^{t-k}\\&=\frac1t\sum_{k=0}^tk\binom{t}{k}p^k(1-p)^{t-k}\\&=\frac1tpt\\&=p\end{align*} Et voila! This experiment actualy simulates what we want to do!

Question for generalization
The above worked because we assumed we could sample from $X$ uniformly. But suppose we cannot. Rather, we can sample from $X$ following a distribution $\mathcal D$ on $X$ with the gurantee that $$\mathcal D(x)\in\left(\frac{(1-\epsilon)}t,\frac{(1+\epsilon)}t\right)$$ for all $x\in X$ and some $\epsilon\ge 0$. Note that $\epsilon=0$ is the uniform case.
The question is, can we do some experiment in the spirit of the above so that we have $$\mathbb P(x_0\text{ picked})\in\left((1-\epsilon)p,(1+\epsilon)p\right)$$

Naive attempt
I attempted to calculate this in the same way as previously. For simplicity, let $\mathcal D(x)=p_x$. The probability that $x_0$ was not picked in the first pick is $$1-p_{x_0}=\sum_{i_1\ne 0}p_{x_{i_1}}$$ The probability that it was again not picked up in the second pick is $$\sum_{i_1,i_2\ne 0}\frac{p_{x_{i_2}}}{1-p_{x_{i_2}}}$$ which comes from rescaling the probabilities after we have picked $x_{i_1}\ne x_0$. Continuing, we get finally \begin{align}\mathbb P(x_0\text{ not picked}\mid N=k)&=\sum_{i_1\ne 0}p_{x_{i_1}}\sum_{i_1,i_2\ne 0}\frac{p_{x_{i_2}}}{1-p_{x_{i_2}}}\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3\ne 0}\frac{p_{i_3}}{1-(p_{x_1}+p_{x_2})}\cdots\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\ne 0}\frac{p_{i_k}}{1-(p_{x_1}+p_{x_2}+\cdots p_{k-1})}\\&=\sum_{i_1\ne 0}\sum_{i_1,i_2\ne 0}\cdots\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\ne 0}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{p_{x_{i_j}}}{1-\sum_{\ell=1}^{j}p_{i_\ell}}\end{align}
Hopefully the last equality is correct (correct me if I am wrong). In any case, subtracting this from $1$ gives us our required probability.
We would now like to bound this first before plugging it in the law of total probability. This is where my problems start. I tried calculating an upper bound by putting the upper bounds for $p_{i_j}$ for the numerators and the the denominators, but the bound becomes negative/undefined (because of a division by $0$) in some cases. Still going forward and plugging that in the law of total probability formula results in a negative/undefined value, which is not really a good thing.
We can probably lower bound this using sampling with replacement, but I don't know how much that helps. Maybe this approach of naively trying the same-ish algorithm does not really work.

So what can we really do? And is this really doable?
Any input is appreciated!

I don't understand why there's even a question here.  It seems you say you can guarantee each element of the population will be picked within a range of probabilities (specific to each element) and you ask how to sample so that this occurs.  I am guessing you have in mind some form of iterative sampling scheme, such as is commonly used for weighted sampling.  But since you don't describe how samples of size larger than 1 are obtained, it's unclear what you're asking about. // Why do you divide by $t$ in your definition of $\mathcal D$ when the population has size $t+1$?

@whuber I am sorry but I don't really follow your comment. My set $X$ has size $t$, not $t+1$. And I am trying to simulate the following experiment : I iterate over all elements of $X$, throw a weighted die with heads probability in the interval I mentioned, and pick it up if heads comes up. Except, I don't want to do it this way, but rather use the samplign access on $X$ I am given (which, in the case I am given an uniform distribution, I can do by sampling a 'binomial number' of elements as I showed). Could you say what is not clear so that I can clarify? Thanks!

When you write a sum from $0$ to $t,$ your population must include at least $t+1$ elements. // You can't iterate in the way you say unless you are selecting with replacement.

But the support of the binomial distribution is from $0$ to $t$. And in what way can't I iterate? I am just picking up items until I have $N$ distinct items.

There are $t+1$ integers between $0$ and $t$ inclusive. // After you pick one number $x,$ the remaining probabilities no longer sum to unity, as they must.  What will you do about that?

Yes that sum has $t+1$ terms, but that's not because of the population. The binomial distribution checks the number of successes in repeated bernoulli trials. I have $t$ items, and I can have $0$ successes allt he way till $t$ successes. Hence the sum. I am really sorry but I am not sure where the confusion is.// And about the things not summing to unity, once we pick an element, we redistribute that mass to all the remaining terms and get ready to pick the next sample, this is standard sampling without replacement.

Yes, that's what I was alluding to--but until now, you hadn't explained how you were sampling and that is crucial.  After all, you can guarantee $x_0$ has the desired chance of being in your sample by drawing one observation initially and after that--no matter what you drew--removing $x_0$ if necessary from the population and sampling from the remainder.

I see. I did mention sampling without replacement in my context, so I thought that was clear. Sorry if it was not. Is that anything else I should clarify?
